# How to deterministic and reproducibly assign increasing port numbers in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ports

I am new to Ansible, but I have to maintain a set of playbooks, which correspond to services to be setup in a given environment. They need to be assigned a port, certificates, etc. This results in many files with lists of essentially always the same names and an assignment to them.

In many cases I think I can easily reuse the service_name as variable, but when mapping to IPs, ports or other numeric identifiers I have not yet figured out a way to deterministically assign them different numbers in a way that is reproducible, and preferably remains the same even when new services are added. I have considered using a SQLite database to store the services from and to generate the values from their ids, but I have no idea how to integrate that with Ansible.

I assume that assigning increasing port numbers is not something entirely new; it is something a lot of sysadmins to on a day-to-day basis so there has to be some way to do that.

**Edit**: We directly add the port numbers etc. in `group_vars/all.yml` like this:

```
ports:
    service1:1024
    service2:1025
    service3:1026
```

The inventory is generated automatically, since we create additional jails (BSD) and depends on the roles that will be executed.

Comment: Since you probably have to add the service to the inventory anyway, what's stopping you to add a specific port number there manually? Or if your inventory is automatically generated, then you should probably solve the problem at the inventory generation level

Comment: Would you please include some Ansible snippets? It's not clear if you are using `group_vars` or adding variables right into inventory files. It's also not clear how your inventory is being generated.

Comment: Have you considered using a service discovery tool like HashiCorp's Consul?

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: I'm not using Ansible.

What I would do is use a random "predictable" number.
According to Ansible doc you can seed the random number generator:

> As of Ansible version 2.3, it’s also possible to initialize the random
>   number generator from a seed. This way, you can create
>   random-but-idempotent numbers:
>
> "{{ 59 |random(seed=inventory_hostname) }} * * * * root
>   /script/from/cron"

So in your case for a port number (I assume unpriviledged) I would go for a variable with something like:

```
port="{{ 32767 |random(start=1024,seed=service_name) }}"
```

Max at 32767 to avoid clashing with any client initiated port (See [Ephemeral port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) for the reason).

Comment: That is a good idea, which I considered, but it makes the increasing part impossible imo. Having certain services which are logically related in a certain port range is probably very desirable.